# I cant save multiple records in database. Only the first row is save

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Only the first row of the datagrid is save. I want to save all of the records:
This is the code of my save button

```
    MysqlConn.Open()
    Try
    Dim Query as String
    For each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv1.Rows
        If row.Cells(0).FormattedValue <> "" And row.Cells(1).FormattedValue <> "" Then
    Query = "insert into items(name,other) values ('"& Cstr(row.Cells(0).FormattedValue) &"' , '"& Cstr(row.Cells(1).FormattedValue) &"')"
    COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
    READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
    dgv1.Rows.Clear()
    End If
    Next
    If result = 0 Then
    Msgbox("Error")
    Else
    Msgbox("Saved")
    End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    MysqlConn.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dgv1.Rows.Clear() inside of your for statement may be the trouble

Comment: Seems like you're really clearing your table right after your first row is inserted into database, move it out of the for statement and that'll do the trick

Comment: ahhh i forgot that I put it inside in the For Each. tnks man, it fixed. I rearrange my code because of the data reader issue

Comment: @Shujinxan make sure to accept my answer if it helped =)